# .show() not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a filter class that filters products residing inside the page.There is a function that works if someone checks the filters.

Filters are check-boxes where every check box contains different value.

What my filter function do is that it checks all the checked  checkboxes from the page and then uses the `data-*` global variable present on the list tages to decide what element to show.

DOM structure of the items will be:

```
<body>
<ul class="products">
<li class="product" data-company="something" data-flavour="something"></li>
<li class="product" data-company="something" data-flavour="something"></li>
.
.
.
.

<li class="product" data-company="something" data-flavour="something"></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Below one shows the the function that does the job.

```
this.filterGridProducts = function() {
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'test12.php',
      data: category,
      success: function(data) {
          $('#limitpage').html(data);
          // $('.product').hide();
          var filteredProducts =$('.product');
          //filter by colour, size, shape etc

          var filterAttributes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
          var selectedFiltersValues = [];
          // for each attribute check the corresponding attribute filters selected
          filterAttributes.each(function() {
              if (this.checked) {
                  var currentFilter = $(this);
                  selectedFiltersValues.push("[data-" + currentFilter.attr('name') + "='" + currentFilter.val() + "']");
                  filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter(selectedFiltersValues.join(','));
              }
          });

          filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter(function() {
              return ($(this).attr('data-price') > first && $(this).attr('data-price') <= second);
          });


          //console.log($('.product').show());
          filteredProducts.each(function(e) {
              console.log($(this).html().show()); // not working
              $(this).show(); // not working
          })

          filteredProducts.show(); // this one is not working as well.

      }

    });
  };
```

`filteredProducts` does contain the elements that need to be filtered but I can't seem to show it.

Ajax call in the above functions loads all the elements present inside the db, The products that come from it are all hidden.

What could be the possible reason for the `.show()` to not work?

Update:

[image]

Comment: I haven't fully read, but it sounds like you're trying to use `.show()` on elements that don't initially exist in the DOM.  You will have to use something like `$(document).on('show', filteredProducts, function(){}`

Comment: `filteredProducts` is the same as `_this.variants`, which we have no idea what is, and then you do `filteredProducts.each(...` but is the `.variants` property even a jQuery object, and if so, where did it come from ?

Comment: @adeneo wait..let me update my question

Comment: @ntgCleaner let me try that as well

Comment: What does `filteredProducts.length` have as value?

Comment: @adeneo that was just a selector

Comment: @trincot 4 is the value

Comment: @ntgCleaner it doesn't work either

Comment: Not the causing problem, but this: `filteredProducts.filter(selectedFiltersValues.join(','))` ... makes no sense. You need to provide a function to `filter`, not a string.

Comment: What if you wrap the final `filteredProducts.show();` like this: `setTimeout(function () { filteredProducts.show(); }, 0);`. Does that change anything?

Comment: Just do  `console.log( filteredProducts.get() )` at the end of the function, right before you try `filteredProducts.show()` and see what you've got, probably nothing.

Comment: Actually, I think your script is interrupted by an error. Did you check the console at all? I am quite sure the bad way you call `filter` should raise a `Type error` exception.

Comment: @adeneo i do get the elements , i will show you that.See, it was all working before but just when i addded an ajax call  and updated my dom elements it stopped working

Comment: i will update my questions with a few screen shots

Comment: @trincot there is no error and i have even updated my question as well.You can see what `filteredProducts` contains.

Comment: Another reason could be that a parent element is hidden. Add this: `filteredProducts.parents().show()`

Comment: @trincot checked this one as well .Nothing changes , same as before.

Comment: how to move into a conversation? can we discuss it there , guys?

Comment: i think it's because of the ajax call ? maybe it has not loaded properly?